# Android Java objModelClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields() returns "$change" as one field

Tags: java, android, class, reflection

In our project we are using data models to store data received from services. So in a particular case when we are inserting data to database, we use **objModelClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields()** method to get all field names, and it is correctly returning all field names of the class but also returning one extra field with name "$change", which does not exists in the class.

Strange thing is, In android studio there was no such problem but when we upgraded to android studio 2.0 this happened.

Though i have applied a quick fix, but i need to properly fix this.
I want to know the why is it happening?

This the function using this method

```
public void insertValuesIntoTable(final String strTableName, ArrayList<Object> alObjClasses,
                                      String strPrimaryKey, String strCompositeKey) {
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db_w = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            //Iterate through every model class Object in the ArrayList and transfer the contents to the DB
            if (alObjClasses != null)
                for (Object objModelClass : alObjClasses) {
                    for (Field field : objModelClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                        //Encrypt value if encryption is enabled & the column is to be encrypted
                        try {
                            field.setAccessible(true);
                            //Test if the table received is Ignore contacts. Minor Hack inserted
                            //So that the same contact data model can be re used. It checks if the
                            //Table is of ignored constant or not then checks if the column exists
                            //in the table or not as that of the field name. Doing this saves
                            //from receiving a SQLConstraint exception stating, "Column not found"
                            if(field.getName().equals("$change"))
                                continue;
                            if(strTableName.equalsIgnoreCase(ContactConstants.TABLE_IGNORED_CONTACTS))
                                if(!field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ContactConstants.TABLE_IGNORED_CONTACTS_NAMES)
                                        && !field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ContactConstants.TABLE_IGNORED_CONTACTS_NUMBERS)
                                        && !field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ContactConstants.TABLE_IGNORED_CONTACTS_EMAIL)
                                        && !field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ContactConstants.TABLE_IGNORED_CONTACTS_CITY)
                                        && !field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ContactConstants.TABLE_IGNORED_CONTACTS_ID))
                                    continue;
                            contentValues.put(field.getName(),
                                    (Constants.ENCRYPTION_PREFERENCE && HelperFunctions.isColumnEncrypted(field.getName()))
                                            ? HelperFunctions.encryptString((String) field.get(objModelClass))
                                            : (String) field.get(objModelClass));
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                         //   e.printStackTrace();
                            //Never thrown since field.setAccessible(true); is called before accessing data
                        }
                        catch ( ClassCastException e) {
                   //         e.printStackTrace();
                            //Never thrown since field.setAccessible(true); is called before accessing data
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        if (db_w.insert(strTableName, null, contentValues) == -1)
                            throw new SQLiteConstraintException();
                    } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
                       // e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("Error - DB", "Error occurred while trying to add data to "
                                + strTableName + " Table, updating data instead.");
                        //Since the entry exists in the DB, it will be updated instead
                        updateEntryInDatabase(db_w, strTableName, strPrimaryKey, strCompositeKey, contentValues);
                    }
                }
            db_w.close();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
         //   e.printStackTrace();
            //Is thrown sometimes when the context of the activity which called it is destroyed mid execution
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e) {
         //   e.printStackTrace();
            //Is thrown sometimes when the context of the activity which called it is destroyed mid execution
        }
    }
```

Comment: My problem is that the item at 0 is "$change" and the item at 48 is "serialversionuid"..... When I see what the long returned by fields[48].getLong(null).

foo[47].getlong = 2131099695
foo[48].getlong = 0
foo[49].getlong =2131099696

Very stumped on what could be causing this.

Comment: can u post some code, for more clarity? in the mean time if your problem is same as mine, check below given solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm struggling with this issue since this morning. It's due to the new functionality of Android Studio 2, Instant run, that adds this field somewhere, as it may be seen while debugging: it implements the interface `com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalChange`.

This issue can be solved by checking the field using the `isSynthetic()` method: it will return `true` for fields generated by the runtime like `$change`, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Relevant Android bug here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204714 — the `$change` field will probably become transient in Android Studio 2.1, which would solve most of the issues it may produce right now.

Comment: @miles the issue was also present in preview channel of Android studio 1.8 (as far as i remember), and it did'nt had instant run or hotswapping feature, though i will check if your solution works.
thanks

Comment: @Kernald yea, i think it will be resolved in future release, but till then need to have a fix which will not break in future releases also.

Comment: @Alok you probably mean Android Studio 1.5? There's no 1.8 version. The first preview ever of the 2.0 (released in November 2015) already had Instant Run.

Comment: @Kernald yea i confirmed, it was 2.0 preview.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know the why is it happening?

Your project already built in Android Studio prior to 2.0 so it is not prepared to use **Instant run** introduced in Android Studio 2.0

> I need to properly fix this

You can solve the issue using: Run > Clean and Rerun, source : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#rerun

or by:

1. Disable Instant run : File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run and
   uncheck Enable Instant Run
2. run the project
3. Enable Instant Run :File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run and check Enable Instant Run